# need to know how to use nosql database with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, cassandra

which NOSQL database will be easiest to use with Ruby ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're going for easy, I would guess MongoDB. There are some great Mongo libraries out there.

- MongoMapper: http://mongomapper.com/
- Mongoid: http://mongoid.org/
- LightMongo: https://github.com/elliotcm/light_mongo
- Mongomatic: http://mongomatic.com/

But each NOSQL database has its own strengths and weaknesses. MongoDB is easy, others focus on other features.

Comment: thanks a lot man. i got a similar response frm other places as well. i am doing this project to learn (or start learning :D) so i guess Mongo is a good place to start . again ... thanks a lot!!